# Correct way for R function to reference columns in user's dataframe?

Tags: r, function, coding-style

I've got a function which operates on 5 columns of a data frame. Eventually I'd like to release this function so that others can use it with their own data.

What is the idiomatic R way to design a function to allow the user to pass in the 5 required columns?

I.e. my function wants to work on a dataframe which contains (at least) columns 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', but in the user's data frame they are labelled differently, for example as 'foo', 'bar', etc...

There are several possibilities although none some particularly elegant to me:

- Require the user to pass in the columns individually as 5 separate vector arguments
- Require the user to name their columns in a specified way and pass in the data frame as a single argument
- Require the user to order their columns in a specified way and pass in the data frame as a single argument
- Pass in the data frame along with a vector consisting of the names of the required columns in this data frame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no one "best" way to do this. The advantage of different methods vary depending on the situation. In this instance, my personal preference is to give the function (at least) two arguments: the data.frame as "data" and a character vector containing the names of the variables.

Then, if you are applying the same operation to each of these, you may supply the character vector as the main argument to `sapply` or `lapply`.

```
myFunc <- function(data=NULL, variables=NULL) {
  if(is.null(data) stop("need a dataset")
  if(is.null(variables) | !is.character(variables) stop("variables improperly supplied")
}
  sapply(variables, FUN=funciton(i) <doStuff to data[, i]>)
```

It is usually better to provide the names of the variables rather than their position, as the position might change across datasets.